# Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_initial_constants() in /home/site/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 26

Tags: php, wordpress

While updating WordPress 3.6.1 on my site I am getting the following error and the site crashes. Why is this happening to my site, and how can I overcome this problem?

Following error arises:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_initial_constants() in /home/adventec/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 26

Comment: it seems that the file where `wp_initial_constants()` function defined is missing.

Comment: i re install the whole file using auto updator but nw i got a different error   Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_multisite() in /home/adventec/public_html/wp-includes/default-constants.php on line 20

Comment: the error still means that one or more files are missing. try to upload all core wp files using ftp and make sure that all files uploaded successfully.

Comment: i upload it to my host except wp_uplods directory.error remain the same

Comment: according to your last error `is_multisite` is defined in wp-includes/load.php. Can you make sure the file exists, and the content is not corrupt?

Comment: iload.php file is there. but remain the same

Comment: i cant overwrite the load.php. it looks empty

Answer (score 0):

Try re-uploading all files & folders - except the **wp-content folder** - from a fresh download of WordPress.

Make sure that you delete the old copies of files & folder before uploading the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

`wp()` is quite essential function. It resides in `functions.php` file (don't confuse with `functions.php` in theme, different thing) and I don't think you can load WP without passing require directive for that file at some point.

So your install seems very broken - either `functions.php` file in core is damaged or something else is broken and makes it skip loading that file.